# Get indexes for Subsample of list of lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list, random

I have several lists of data in python:

```
a = [2,45,1,3]
b = [4,6,3,6,7,1,37,48,19]
c = [45,122]
total = [a,b,c]
```

I want to get `n` random indexes from them:

```
n = 7
# some code
result = [[1,3], [2,6,8], [0,1]] # or
result = [[0], [0,2,6,8], [0,1]] # or
result = [[0,1], [0,2,3,6,8], []] # or any other
```

The idea - it takes randomly any elements (indexes of that elements) from any arrays, but total count of them must be `n`.

So my idea - generate random indexes:

```
n = 7
total_len = sum([len(el) for el in total])
inds = random.sample(range(total_length), n))
```

But how then get such indexes?
I think about `np.cumsum()` and shift indixes after that but can't find elegant solution...

---

P.S.
Actually, I need to use it for loading data from a several `csv` files using `skiprow` option. So my idea - get indexes for every file, and this let me load only necessary rows from every file.
So my real task:
i have several csv files of different length and need to get `n` random rows from them.
My idea:

```
lengths = my_func_to_get_lengths_for_every_csv(paths) # list of lengths
# generate random subsamle of indexes
skip = ...
for ind, fil in enumerate(files):
    pd.read_csv(fil, skiprows=skip[ind])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you mean?

```
relative_inds = []
min_bound = 0
for lst in total:
    relative_inds.append([i - min_bound for i in inds if min_bound <= i < min_bound + len(lst)])
    min_bound += len(lst)
```

Comment: Yep, it is exact what I want! Thank you!

Comment: Happy to help :D

Answer (score 2):

You could flatten the list first and then take your samples:

```
total_flat = [item for sublist in total for item in sublist]
inds = random.sample(total_flat , k=n)
```

Comment: Thank you for responce! Actually, I need to use it for loading data from a several `csv` files using `skiprow` option. So I can't use such approach - I really need indexes for every list.

Comment: Why don't you have a list of all available indices and then take the subset? I do not understand your requirement.

Comment: @Mikhail_Sam Python's csv module doesn't have a "skiprow" option. What library are you using?

Comment: I add example in my question. Take a look pls

Comment: @Mikhail_Sam If you use pandas, I suggest you create a question with that tag. Perhaps there's a good way to do the entire thing properly in pandas.